# Can't start MongoDB on localhost for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am a beginner to node.js and MongoDB. I am trying to setup a basic project like so.

In my project dir I run `node init`, accept the default values and then run `npm install --save mongodb`. In my index.js I have the following code:

```
// Import the mongodb module
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:3333/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

Now when I run `node index.js` I get the following error:

`failed to connect to server [localhost:3333] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3333]`

I have tried changing the port number but still get the same error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to setup mongo server first. The code that you have written is to connect to that server.

Comment: @VipinKumar how do I set it up?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/ is good place to start

Answer (score 2):

By default the MongoDB server is running on port 27017. You need to change the connection string to `mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install MongoDB if you don't already have it installed. Visit [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community) site to download.
Follow the instructions there on how to start it up and running, after that try running your app again.

Also by default MongoDB runs on port `27017` so your url should point to `localhost:27017`.

```
// Import the mongodb module
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```